# Preserve colors in piped ack-grep

Tags: bash, ack

`grep` uses `--color=always` to preserve colors in a piped output. But this doesn't work in `ack-grep`, what is the `ack` equivalent?

Comment: Have you tried just `ack --color`? According to the documentation, this should do it.

Comment: --color doesn't work. i just did a "ls | ack xxx" and the only thing in color is the matched pattern. the other letters are not blue, the default color if i do a ls.

Comment: Well, that has to do with ls, that behaves similarly if the output is piped. You get the same if you do `ls | grep --color=always`, also only colors for the matched patterns. Actually I am correcting myself, you could do `ls --color=always | grep/ack`, then `grep/ack` does indeed get colored input, but they still both behave the same and ignore the input color and generate color for the match only.